# Discord.net: UserVoiceStateUpdated Event not fired when User initially connects to voice channel

Tags: c#, events, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to have my bot recognize when any guild member joins a specific voice channel and then react to it. I tried to do this by subscribing to the **UserVoiceStateUpdated** event. This basically works as expected, however when a user first joins any voice channel, the event is not fired. When the user then switches from one voice channel to another, it works fine. As soon as you completely disconnect the user from voice and reconnect it once again requires changing the voice channel before my event handler is executed.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the intended behavior? If so, can I somehow achieve this in another way?

---

Just to clarify again, this is what I'm doing and how the bot reacts to it:

1. User connects to voice - UserVoiceStateUpdated is not fired
2. User then switches to another voice channel - UserVoiceStateUpdated triggers my event handler correctly
3. User switches voice channel once again - UserVoiceStateUpdated triggers again
4. User disconnects from voice completely - UserVoiceStateUpdated triggers
5. User reconnects to any voice channel - UserVoiceStateUpdated handler is not executed
6. User switches voice channels - UserVoiceStateUpdated triggers as expected

---

Tried with both a .net Framework 4.7 and .net Core 2.0, as well as Discord.net versions 1.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2. Always the same.

Comment: Can't help you without showing your code.

Comment: `_client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += HandleUserVoiceStateUpdated;`

this is literally all the code. `HandleUserVoiceStateUpdated` can be just a simple log message.

Comment: You should open a bug report on their github.

https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues

Comment: I was thinking about that as well but wanted to first confirm that this is indeed a bug and I'm not just using it wrong.

Comment: Their documentation clearly states that UserVoiceStateUpdated is fired when a user joins, leaves, or moves voice channels. If you're able to reproduce that then you might be able to file a bug report.

Comment: I can't test it now since I'm not at home, but I might play with it later.

Comment: link to github issue: https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after adding some more logging I found that every time the event did not trigger this message was logged: "A UserVoiceStateUpdated handler is blocking the gateway task."

I then started completely from scratch, created a new discord app, bot user, etc. and it worked. I can't really explain how that solved the problem but it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the `A UserVoiceStateUpdated handler is blocking the gateway task` you just need to put the contents of all of your UserVoiceStateUpdated handlers into a

```cs
_=Task.Run(()=>{
  //your code here
})
```

statement, this runs it on another thread and allows the gateway task to continue proccessing